# How to make my regex achieve my goal?

Tags: regex

This is part of my code:

```
String subArray[]=sub.split(" ");
StringBuilder patternbuilder=new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
    patternbuilder.append("("+subArray[i]+" )"+"?");
}
String subpattern=patternbuilder.toString();
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(subpattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(para);
while (matcher.find()) {
    NamedEntity subEntity=new NamedEntity(jCas, matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    subEntity.setValue(matcher.group());
}
```

This my regular expression: `(adam )?(hecktman )?`

This is the example document:

> prior to microsoft, adam was a consultant with andersen consulting for three years. while at andersen consulting, adam worked with clients including those in financial services, government, and utilities. adam received a ((nam: bachelor of science)) in commerce and business administration from the university of illinois at urbana-champaign. he also holds a master of business administration degree.

I want to extract the pattern which there must be at least one word of `"adam hecktman"` in it but I always can't make it with my regex. I always get `""` an empty string. How to achieve my goal?

Comment: Try `(adam)|(hecktman)`. Yours allows both of them to be missing because of the `?´.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` in regular expressions means that the group or char preceding it can optionally occur. In your cause this means that `adam` may occur and `hecktman` may occur. So they are both allowed to be present but also lacking, hence the empty string satisfies this regex.

You want one of both words to be actually present so use the `|` operator. This means that one of both sides should be present (presuming there isn't a `?` following the sub expression). In your case  `(adam)|(hecktman)` means that the regex will match lines containing `adam` or `hecktman`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
((adam)( hecktman)?)|(hecktman)
```